# Why can't I reset margin-bottom to 0 when using react and antd?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend, antd

I'm practicing react and I put `<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/reset.css" />` in the head of index.html to reset the styles. However, `<h1>` has a `margin-bottom:0.5em` which cannot be reset. In Chrome debugger, I find these styles as below, but I never wrote styles in the upper part. I'm wondering where it is from and how can I reset margin-bottom to 0.(I'm using create-react-app and antd components in my exercise project.)[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding `* { margin: 0; }` to your CSS?

The `*` will target *all* of the elements.

Comment: Yes, I've tried and it does not work, but if I select that h1 element exactly and add `margin:0;`, it works. However, I don't think I should use this way to address this problem because I don't want to add `margin:0;` every time I use h1. Also, I want to figure out why the reset.css does not work and where is that style in the upper part from.

Comment: @reallywannacryifnotgetanswer, can you screenshot the `h1` code in the resets.css file?

Comment: `html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,del,dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,small,strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,b, u, i, center,dl, dt, dd, ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label, legend,table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure,figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section,summary,time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}`

Comment: Yeah I think that the best solution would be to add `h1 { margin: 0; }` whenever needed. Not very efficient but will probably be the best way to do it for now. Hope this helps 

Comment: Thanks but do you know where is those styles from? Is it because I'm using react or antd?

Comment: Yes it might be. If this doesn't mess up anything, try reseting the React app to get back to default styles.

Also, have you looked through *all* the code for `h1` tags to see if they are the issue?

Comment: Yes, I'm just beginning and only have 2 css files.

Comment: Ok that's strange. Could you send me a link to the folder of your code? Could be a google drive link set to "view only".

I'd like to take a closer look.

Comment: Here's the github repository [link](https://github.com/tyz98/react_products_management). There's some Chinese in my code but it won't affect understanding. Thanks.

Comment: Okay I think that the best solution would be to just go with it for now. Will you plan to use an h1 in your project? If so, just do what I said before:

> I think that the best solution would be to add h1 { margin: 0; } whenever needed.

But yes, I think the `margin-bottom: 0.5em;` is coming from Ant.design. Not completely sure but I don't know where else it would come from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219846/discussion-between-reallywannacryifnotgetanswer-and-brayden-w).

Answer (score 0):

You're using react, so make a component with the style you want. If it's an h1 with no margin on the bottom, just do,

```
// styledHeading.module.css
styledHeading {
    margin-bottom: 0
}

// styledHeading.js
import styles from './styleHeading.module.css

// className for additional css classes
const StyledHeading = ({text, className}) => 
    <h1 className={`${styles.styledHeading} ${className}`}>{text}</h1>
```

Comment: Yes, I know this will address this problem, but I just want to figure out where thoses styles are from and why reset.css does not work.